# Compiler which can compile c++17 lambda inheritance with parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++17

I read about the [using function declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) and I wanted to compile the last example. This is :

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename... Ts>
struct Overloader : Ts... {
    using Ts::operator()...; // exposes operator() from every base
};

template <typename... T>
constexpr auto make_overloader(T&&... t) {
    return Overloader<T...>{std::forward<T>(t)...};
}

int main() {
    auto o = make_overloader([] (auto const& a) {std::cout << a;},
                             [] (float f) {std::cout << 13 << f;});
}
```

Even if I already know and understand what it will do, I would like to compile and test it.
 However, neither clang-4.0 and g++-7.0 seems to be able to compile it at the moment. Is there any place with any compiler I could try it ?

Comment: If the latest versions of both GCC and Clang can't do something, it's pretty much guaranteed that no other compiler can either (modulo bugs). Unless it's some independent project, likely a fork of one of them.

Comment: This feature was voted into the working draft ~a month ago. Implementing things take time.

Comment: @TC: I still don't understand how OP's example would compile even if the declarator list feature was approved. `Overloader` is not an aggregate because it has a base class. Also, `make_overloader` is receiving a generic lambda, so is `Overloader` is templated appropriately to handle that either? Can you help me out?

Comment: @AndyG I think there was a aggregate initialization with base classes change in C++17?  Like, each of them get a "slot" in the `{}` list?  I do not recall, and haven't played enough with C++17 to have a good instinct.  I see no problem with `make_overloader` other than a missing `std::decay`: in particular `Overloader<std::decay_t<T>...>`

Comment: @Yakk: Maybe you're referring to [the following](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization): "Each direct public base, (since C++17) array element, or non-static class member, in order of array subscript/appearance in the class definition, is copy-initialized from the corresponding clause of the initializer list." But then wouldn't [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eccaa45a6edc5c87) work? Perhaps it hasn't been implemented in gcc or clang yet.

Comment: Otherwise, if I write a forwarding constructor in C++14 with template recursion, I can get all this to work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98ea07a35a768eaa

Comment: @AndyG In C++17 aggregates can have public bases. If you are testing stuff on the cutting edge, I'd suggest Wandbox (which has builds from trunk) rather than Coliru. (That didn't ping, BTW.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[P0195](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0195r1.html), the proposed language extension that allows for:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct Overloader : Ts... {
    using Ts::operator()...; // <== ill-formed without p0195
};
```

was only accepted into C++ in Issaquah a few weeks ago (November 2016). It's not surprising that gcc or clang haven't implemented it yet. Give them time.

The workaround for now is to create a linear hierarchy for `Overloader` instead.

Comment: Where did you find the adoption status of P0195? It isn't marked as "adopted" on [http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/)

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I trust [Botond](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2016/11/25/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-issaquah-november-2016/)

Comment: Linear?  Slacker.  Binary!